# How do I get dagger 2 to work with Android studio java library project

Tags: java, gradle, dagger-2

I have an app module (which is my app) and a java library project module (called api) I'd like to use dagger 2 in the api module but the annotation processor is not working, the dagger prefixed classes (ex. DaggerApiComponent) are not being generated like how one would expect. Any help would be greatly appreciated and yes I am using gradle.

Comment: I'am not sure but maybe this is your problem: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issues/18/support-java-plugin Looks like the `android-apt` plugin (which is used by dagger to generate code based on annotations) only works for android modules.

Comment: yea then why call dagger 2 a java library, anyway I'm close to figuring it out once I do ill post an answer

Comment: I spent hours on this issue, and was unable to resolve it, until i switched to **Project** view and saw that the generated classes were under `release` build type. After switching to `release` build type things magically started working.

I'm also using newer `annotationProcessor` from new build tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix this, the android-apt plugin for gradle is only available when `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` is used. So in a java library where you cannot use the `com.android.application` plugin you need to instead use the plugin `apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"` after applying this plugin you can use the apt configuration for dagger's compiler dependency `apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2"` in the dependencies block. Also you need to `apply plugin: "idea"` for `net.ltgt.apt` to work correctly, if you don't apply the idea plugin the annotation processor generates the dagger factory classes but it doesn't get included in the IDE's sourceSet, so dont forget to apply the idea plugin. so finally my build script looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.6"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: "idea"

dependencies {
    // Dagger 2 and Compiler
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! wasted days on this one!